# Trouble building ffmpeg with cuda for windows 32 with visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, build, visual-studio-2022, mingw32

Here is my building process

I open mingw32 from the **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022**

then in the mingw32 shell:

```
# cd /
# ./c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio/2022/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars32.bat
# cd ~
# pacman -Sy diffutils git make gcc yasm pkg-config --noconfirm
# git clone --depth 1 https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg 
# git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git nv-codec-headers 
# cd nv-codec-headers/
# make PREFIX=/usr/local
# make install PREFIX=/usr/local
# cd ..
# mkdir nv_sdk
# cp -r /c/Program\ Files/NVIDIA\ GPU\ Computing\ Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/lib/Win32/* nv_sdk
# cp -r /c/Program\ Files/NVIDIA\ GPU\ Computing\ Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/include/* nv_sdk
# export PATH="/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x86/":$PATH
# export PATH="/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/bin/":$PATH
# ./configure --disable-everything --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=hevc --enable-cross-compile --disable-avdevice --disable-swresample --disable-postproc --disable-avfilter --target-os=mingw32 --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-nonfree --toolchain=msvc --extra-cflags=-I../nv_sdk --extra-ldflags=" -m32 -L../nv_sdk" --enable-shared --shlibdir=SHARED_LIBS --arch=x86_32 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-w32threads
# make -j8
# make install
```

first I have a bunch of warnings during the making looking like that:
`libavutil/opt.c(1075): warning C4133: 'fonction' : types incompatibles - de 'AVPixelFormat *' à 'int *'`

And finally the make install returns :

```
EXTERN_PREFIX="_" AR="lib.exe" NM="dumpbin.exe -symbols" ./compat/windows/makedef libavutil/libavutil.ver libavutil/adler32.o libavutil/aes.o libavutil/aes_ctr.o libavutil/audio_fifo.o libavutil/avsscanf.o libavutil/avstring.o libavutil/base64.o libavutil/blowfish.o libavutil/bprint.o libavutil/buffer.o libavutil/camellia.o libavutil/cast5.o libavutil/channel_layout.o libavutil/color_utils.o libavutil/cpu.o libavutil/crc.o libavutil/des.o libavutil/detection_bbox.o libavutil/dict.o libavutil/display.o libavutil/dovi_meta.o libavutil/downmix_info.o libavutil/encryption_info.o libavutil/error.o libavutil/eval.o libavutil/fifo.o libavutil/file.o libavutil/file_open.o libavutil/film_grain_params.o libavutil/fixed_dsp.o libavutil/float_dsp.o libavutil/frame.o libavutil/hash.o libavutil/hdr_dynamic_metadata.o libavutil/hdr_dynamic_vivid_metadata.o libavutil/hmac.o libavutil/hwcontext.o libavutil/hwcontext_d3d11va.o libavutil/hwcontext_dxva2.o libavutil/imgutils.o libavutil/integer.o libavutil/intmath.o libavutil/lfg.o libavutil/lls.o libavutil/log.o libavutil/log2_tab.o libavutil/lzo.o libavutil/mastering_display_metadata.o libavutil/mathematics.o libavutil/md5.o libavutil/mem.o libavutil/murmur3.o libavutil/opt.o libavutil/parseutils.o libavutil/pixdesc.o libavutil/pixelutils.o libavutil/random_seed.o libavutil/rational.o libavutil/rc4.o libavutil/reverse.o libavutil/ripemd.o libavutil/samplefmt.o libavutil/sha.o libavutil/sha512.o libavutil/slicethread.o libavutil/spherical.o libavutil/stereo3d.o libavutil/tea.o libavutil/threadmessage.o libavutil/time.o libavutil/timecode.o libavutil/tree.o libavutil/twofish.o libavutil/tx.o libavutil/tx_double.o libavutil/tx_float.o libavutil/tx_int32.o libavutil/utils.o libavutil/version.o libavutil/video_enc_params.o libavutil/x86/cpu.o libavutil/x86/cpuid.o libavutil/x86/fixed_dsp.o libavutil/x86/fixed_dsp_init.o libavutil/x86/float_dsp.o libavutil/x86/float_dsp_init.o libavutil/x86/imgutils.o libavutil/x86/imgutils_init.o libavutil/x86/lls.o libavutil/x86/lls_init.o libavutil/x86/tx_float.o libavutil/x86/tx_float_init.o libavutil/xga_font_data.o libavutil/xtea.o > libavutil/avutil-57.def
Could not create temporary library.
make: *** [ffbuild/library.mak:118: libavutil/avutil-57.dll] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong ?
shall I install others packets from pacman?

Comment: options used:
--disable-everything 
--enable-decoder=h264
--enable-decoder=hevc
--enable-cross-compile 
--disable-avdevice 
--disable-swresample 
--disable-postproc 
--disable-avfilter 
--target-os=mingw32 
--enable-cuda-nvcc 
--enable-nonfree 
--toolchain=msvc
--extra-cflags=-I../nv_sdk 
--extra-ldflags=" -m32 -L../nv_sdk" 
--enable-shared --shlibdir=DLLSSSS 
--arch=x86_32 
--enable-runtime-cpudetect 
--enable-w32threads

Answer (score 0):

I open mingw32 from the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022

maybe you should  open it in X86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022